# XML Keyref with value 'null'

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, schema

I have an important issue with XSD, XML, XPath and so on.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<biblioteka xmlns:aw="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" aw:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <gatunek>
            <identyfikator id="fan"/>
    </gatunek>
    <dział>
        <książka gatunek_id="fan"/>   
    </dział>
</biblioteka>
```

And this is schema.xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="biblioteka" type="moja_biblioteka">

        <xs:unique name="IDUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath="gatunek/identyfikator"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@id"/>
        </xs:unique>

        <xs:keyref name="gatunekIDKeyRef" refer="IDUnique">
            <xs:selector xpath="dział/książka"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@gatunek_id" />            
        </xs:keyref>
    </xs:element>

     <xs:complexType name="moja_biblioteka">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="gatunek"/>
                <xs:element ref="dział" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="gatunek">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="identyfikator" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="id" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="dział">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="książka" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>       
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="książka">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="gatunek_id" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="[a-z]{3,6}"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

All seems to be fine, but it's not :/. When I validate this (I use NetBeans) I get this error message:

**Key 'gatunekIDKeyRef' with value 'null' not found for identity constraint of element 'biblioteka'. [10]**

I fighting with these for hours, others solutions I found of stackoverflow are not helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be two errors involved here.  Your error is declaring a top-level element named `książka` but then not referring to it from the type for `dział`, and instead declaring a local element with the same name.

When I validate your sample document against your sample schema using Saxon, I get the warning

> Local element declaration matches the name of a global element, and allows any content. Did you mean to write ref='książka' instead of name='książka'? To suppress this warning, add type='xs:anyType'

Saxon reports, however, that the document is valid.

When I change the declaration for `dział` to

```
<xs:element name="dział">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <!--<xs:element name="książka" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>-->
      <xs:element ref="książka" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>       
</xs:element>
```

both Saxon and Xerces-J believe the document is valid against the schema.

With the original schema, on the other hand, Xerces-J gives me the same error message you report; I do not know why.  I think this is the second error involved.

Comment: Thanks, your change solved my problem. I would never find that alone :D